# Adwords MCC ID Java App

Tags: google-ads-api

I am new to Adwords api so excuse my lack of knowledge.

Just wanted to check if there is any way to programmatically pull the MCC client ID without physically adding it in the session builder code?

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [CustomerService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201702/CustomerService)

> CustomerService provides information about your accounts. It has a
>   getCustomers() method that takes no arguments and returns a list of
>   Customer objects containing fields such as customerId, currencyCode,
>   and dateTimeZone. CustomerService also has a mutate() method that can
>   be used to update various attributes of a customer, including the
>   autoTaggingEnabled and conversionTrackingSetting fields.

Reference: [Managing Accounts](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview)

*Read carefully the annotations for your Adwords API version.*

Comment: Thanks so much for that, that is exactly what i was looking for! Helps heaps